# running a python script against all files in a folder on macOS

Tags: python, sh, zsh

On macOS zsh the following command runs successfully:

```
python2 pythonscript.py keyfile.key "My File Name.extension" "processed_My File Name.extension"
```

basically I am doing some processing against some files using Python and the output file will have processed_ appended to the file name. The problem is I have tons of files so I tried:

```
find . -name "*.extension" -execdir printf '%s\n' {} + -exec sh -c 'python2 pythonscript.py keyfile.key "$0"  processed_+"$0"' \;
```

But no output file is produced when run like this. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `$0` is the name of the script, not the first parameter.  It would me much smarter to change your script to handle multiple files internally, like `for name in sys.argv[3:]:`

Comment: If modifying the Python script is feasible, you should consider utilising the *glob* module to find the files that you want to process. It will certainly be more efficient than invoking python once for every file you need to process

Comment: find . -name "*.filextension" -execdir printf '%s\n' {} + -exec sh -c

will return me the file names. Is this not {0} ? I need to pass the file name (which might contain spaces) to the python  script like this:

python2 pyscript.py somekeyfile.ley filename output_file

Comment: Why are you invoking `sh` if all you want to do is running Python? Just do a `-exec python2 .... {} .... \;`

Answer (score 1):

I was able to run this successfully using:

```
find * -name "*.extension" -exec zsh -c 'for result; do python2 pythonscript.py keyfile.key "$result" processed_"$result"; done' _ {} +
```